# Python.dll could not be loaded with PyScripter

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyscripter

I'm trying to configure **PyScripter** with QGIS. I've installed it using OSGeo4W and I'm following instructions to setup a `pyscripter.bat` file by copying content of `qgis.bat` file. I have the following code:

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\env.bat
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
Start "PyScripter" /B "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\PyScripter.exe" --python27 --pythondllpath=C:\OSGeo4W\bin
```

However when I run this file I get the following error and PyScripter exits after that.

[image]

Where am I wrong?

Comment: look at [Configure PyScripter to use with QGIS (and still use arcpy) on Windows](http://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/configure-pyscripter-qgis/)

Comment: @gene I think you should post this link with a summary of it as an Answer

Answer (score 3):

Following Polygeo's suggestion:

It is a problem of Python and the Windows registry:

- For the moment, PyScripter can only use the Python versions that have entries in the Windows registry (as the official Python distribution versions, the [Enthought Python Distribution](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/) or ArcPy)
- The standalone QGIS installer installs Python 2.7 but does not create any registry entries (as the [Anaconda Scientific Python Distribution](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/), for example) so PyScripter does not recognize it.

However, there are solutions to use PyScripter  with these versions. For the standalone QGIS version, one of them is given in [Configure PyScripter to use with QGIS (and still use arcpy) on Windows](http://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/configure-pyscripter-qgis/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this but I already was following these links. I just changed --pythondllpath=C:\OSGeo4W\bin with --pythondllpath=%OSGeo4W_ROOT%\bin and It started working